# How to find the first occurence of a number+word combo after a particular string?

Tags: python, regex, string

I have a string which is essentially a page's worth of text.

A sample would be: "Ultimately, biscuits earwax 12 as well as Reading Time: up to 15 minutes".

What I want to extract is the first occurence of a '2-digit number + minutes' AFTER the substring "Reading time".  My string is MUCH larger and has some numbers scattered around everywhere, so I want to use regex to do this but I'm not sure how to proceed from hereon in.

**Example:**

*Input*: "Ultimately, biscuits earwax 12 as well as Reading Time: up to 15 minutes"

*Output*: "15 minutes"

Comment: You can partition string ```str.partition('Reading Time')```, then use regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is it in one line:

`print(s[s.find("Reading Time") + s[s.find("Reading Time") : len(s)].find("minutes") - 3 : s.find("Reading Time") + s[s.find("Reading Time") : len(s)].find("minutes") + 7])`

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit of a departure from regex, but why not leveraging a more powerful natural language processing Python library to achieve this?

Here's an example with spaCy's `Matcher` (https://spacy.io/usage/rule-based-matching should be more flexible and easy to use than regex, if you accept the additional dependency):

```py
import spacy
from spacy.matcher import Matcher

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
matcher = Matcher(nlp.vocab)

pattern = [{"LOWER": "reading"}, # we require 'reading time' to be in the pattern
           {"LOWER": "time"},
           {"OP": "*"}, # there may be some stuff (optionally)
           {"LIKE_NUM": True}, # then we look for a number and 'minutes'
           {"LOWER": "minutes"}]

matcher.add("duration", [pattern])

# some tests, and just two of them should give in output something
tests = ["Ultimately, biscuits earwax 12 as well as Reading Time: up to 15 minutes",
         "I wonder if this will take a reading time of more than 15 or 17 minutes in the end",
         "Will it take us more than 50 minutes?",
         "I don't have anything like 'reading time'",
         "spaCy rocks!"]

# print results for each example
for test in tests:
  doc = nlp(test)
  matches = matcher(doc)
  for match_id, start, end in matches:
    print(doc[end-2:end]) # just get the final two tokens
```

By tweaking the `pattern` you should be all set to match sentences according to your needs.